# Azure Stream Analytics: Concatenating rows

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I have this azure stream analytics receiving events from event hub and outputting to blob.

Each input corresponds to only one geo-position.

I also have another input which is a blob reference, where there are areas defined in geojson.

What I need is to match my position to the areas and return one single line per position with a column areas as a result of a concatenation of the matched areas.

Example:
Event Hub

```
{"longitude": 0, "latitude": 0, "posId":1}
```

Blob

```
[
  {
    "boxName": "mediterraneanbox",
    "geoJSON": "{\"geometry\":{\"type\": \"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[-25.7,25.5,0.0],[-12.06,25.5,0.0],[1.58,25.5,0.0],[15.22,25.5,0.0],[28.86,25.5,0.0],[42.5,25.5,0.0],[42.5,30.04,0.0],[42.5,34.58,0.0],[42.5,39.12,0.0],[42.5,43.66,0.0],[42.5,48.2,0.0],[28.86,48.2,0.0],[15.22,48.2,0.0],[1.58,48.2,0.0],[-12.06,48.2,0.0],[-25.7,48.2,0.0],[-25.7,43.66,0.0],[-25.7,39.12,0.0],[-25.7,34.58,0.0],[-25.7,30.04,0.0],[-25.7,25.5,0.0]]]}}"
  },
  {
    "boxName": "jordanmoroccotunisiabox",
    "geoJSON": "{\"geometry\":{\"type\": \"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[-19,26,0.0],[-5.6,26,0.0],[7.8,26,0.0],[21.2,26,0.0],[34.6,26,0.0],[48,26,0.0],[48,30.4,0.0],[48,34.8,0.0],[48,39.2,0.0],[48,43.6,0.0],[48,48,0.0],[34.6,48,0.0],[21.2,48,0.0],[7.8,48,0.0],[-5.6,48,0.0],[-19,48,0.0],[-19,43.6,0.0],[-19,39.2,0.0],[-19,34.8,0.0],[-19,30.4,0.0],[-19,26,0.0]]]}}"
  },
 ]
```

ASA Query

```
wITH [flattened] AS
(
    SELECT 
        GetMetadataPropertyValue(input, 'EventId') AS Id,
        input.PartitionId,
        d.arrayvalue.positionReport.longitude,
        d.arrayvalue.positionReport.latitude,
        CreatePoint(TRY_CAST( d.arrayvalue.positionReport.latitude AS FLOAT), TRY_CAST(d.arrayvalue.positionReport.longitude AS FLOAT)) point
    FROM input partition by PartitionId
    CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(input.messages) as d
    WHERE d.arrayvalue.positionReport.timeL IS NOT NULL AND d.arrayvalue.positionReport.longitude IS NOT NULL AND
    d.arrayvalue.positionReport.latitude IS NOT NULL
),
[bounded] as (
    select f.id, b.boxname, f.PartitionId
    FROM [flattened] f partition by PartitionId
    join (
        SELECT boxname, UDF.JSONparse([geoJSON]) geoJSON
        FROM [boundingboxes]
    ) b ON ST_WITHIN(f.point, b.geoJSON.geometry) =1
),
[merged] as
(
    select collect() as bbox, id, PartitionId
    from [bounded] partition by PartitionId
    group by TUMBLINGWINDOW(microsecond, 1), id, PartitionId
),
[match] as (
    SELECT f.id, f.longitude, f.latitude, UDF.CleanBBox(m.bbox) as bbox, 
        CONCAT(
            CASE WHEN ST_WITHIN(f.point, UDF.JsonParse('{"type": "Polygon","coordinates":[[[-25.7,25.5,0.0],[-12.06,25.5,0.0],[1.58,25.5,0.0],[15.22,25.5,0.0],[28.86,25.5,0.0],[42.5,25.5,0.0],[42.5,30.04,0.0],[42.5,34.58,0.0],[42.5,39.12,0.0],[42.5,43.66,0.0],[42.5,48.2,0.0],[28.86,48.2,0.0],[15.22,48.2,0.0],[1.58,48.2,0.0],[-12.06,48.2,0.0],[-25.7,48.2,0.0],[-25.7,43.66,0.0],[-25.7,39.12,0.0],[-25.7,34.58,0.0],[-25.7,30.04,0.0],[-25.7,25.5,0.0]]]}')) = 1 THEN '[mediterraneanbox]' ELSE '' END ,
            CASE WHEN ST_WITHIN(f.point, UDF.JsonParse('{"type": "Polygon","coordinates":[[[-19,26,0.0],[-5.6,26,0.0],[7.8,26,0.0],[21.2,26,0.0],[34.6,26,0.0],[48,26,0.0],[48,30.4,0.0],[48,34.8,0.0],[48,39.2,0.0],[48,43.6,0.0],[48,48,0.0],[34.6,48,0.0],[21.2,48,0.0],[7.8,48,0.0],[-5.6,48,0.0],[-19,48,0.0],[-19,43.6,0.0],[-19,39.2,0.0],[-19,34.8,0.0],[-19,30.4,0.0],[-19,26,0.0]]]}')) = 1 THEN '[jordanmoroccotunisiabox]' ELSE '' END
        ) as boundingbox
    FROM [flattened] f partition by PartitionId left join [merged] m partition by PartitionId
    on f.PartitionId = m.PartitionId and f.id = m.id and datediff(microsecond, f, m) between 0 and 1
)
select *, CASE WHEN bbox != boundingbox THEN 'ERROR' ELSE 'OK' END val from [match]
```

This is not returning me good results as I sometimes see duplicates in the areas. I thought this was cause by windowing so i put the smallest value possible (microsecond and 1) but that does not seem to work.

==========================================================================
Edit 1

Seems my problem was grouping by the message id, which was not truly unique, so I changed to use [eventId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/reference/getmetadatapropertyvalue#unique-eventid-property) which is unique.

My issue now is that I was forced to increase SUs and i believe this is because i'm not doing partition by, which i want to do by PartitionId but can't because when i try to start the job i get an error saying that the number of partition is not always the same.

==========================================================================
Edit 2

I managed to have partition by partitionid in the query (added a new column in flattened to pass the partitionid) which significantly improved the number of input events read.

Anyway, looking at the output, it seems this is still not working for all cases. I still get things like:

```
{"id":"8214ab10-d62d-18cc-3ca2-91dff9718043","longitude":-9.25,"latitude":32.312666666666665,"bbox":"","boundingbox":"[mediterraneanbox][jordanmoroccotunisiabox]","val":"ERROR"}
```

I'm expecting for fields bbox and boundingbox to have the same value.

Comment: Please post current output and the results you want.

Comment: It looks like current issue is to do with partitioning, can you please update the query with the one that failed to start? The query in the question as of June 26 doesn't have partition by partitionId.

Comment: Hi @VigneshChandramohan, it does not because i can't make it work at all, it always gives me error when i try to start the job, but what i basically did was add partition by partitionid after all joins of flattened and the input itself.